# uploadArchives does not upload artifacts generated from other gradle files

Tags: gradle, nexus

In my build.gradle, I have war task which generates a war file and couple tasks which generate jar file. Jar generating tasks are defined in other gradle files and are imported in main build.gralde using apply from clause.

Problem is uploadArchives only uploads war file and does not upload jar files which are generated from other files.

What could be the potential cause of problem here?

My build.gradle looks like as follows

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'maven'

war {
   .... // generates war file
}

apply from: 'Createjar1.gradle'  // creates jar1
apply from: 'Createjar2.gradle'  // creates jar2
apply from: 'Createjar3.gradle'  // creates jar3

uploadArchives {
repositories {
    mavenDeployer {
        repository(url:"${nexusURL}") {
            authentication(userName: 'username', password: 'password')
        }
        snapshotRepository(url: "${nexusURL}") {
            authentication(userName: 'username', password: 'password')
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the 'maven' plugin will upload any artifacts contained in the 'archives' configuration. Your WAR is automatically added to that configuration but additional artifacts have to be explicitly defined.

```
artifacts {
    archives jar1Task
    archives jar2Task
    archives jar3Task
}
```

Comment: This gives error message that artifact with name already exists. I was able to resolve the problem using following:

archives file: file("abc.jar"), name: "abc", type: 'jar',
archives file: file("xyz.jar"), name: "xyz", type: 'jar'

Also, you need to add following to uploadArchives for every artifact you add in archives

addFilter('abc') {artifact, file ->
    artifact.name == 'abc'
 }

Comment: I believe you could get around that issue by giving your artifacts unique classifiers.

Comment: classifiers don't apply to my artifacts.